# Updating Task with Mobile SDK (Native Application)

Tags: soql, mobile, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, sfdcmobilesdk-android

What is the easiest way to update entities like Tasks via the Mobile SDK?
How about creating or deleting entities?

Comment: There is a way to update records based on what type of project you are creating(native, hybrid_local, etc.). It's just an API call so what you mean by easiest way?

Comment: it is a native android app (I am using the sdk with SalesForceActivities and SOQL queries/callback)

Comment: do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried a native one, but a hybrid_local. It's just a matter of calling a javascript function there.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the source code of sample RestExplorer native app for reference? You could modify that to do task related operations.